# ReactJS nested looping on JSON object

Tags: reactjs

I did not get the exact answer I needed to fix the issue I am seeing.
I have a JSON object like below,

```css
   {  
      "id":1,
      "time":"2018-04-15 22:04:21",
      "alert":{  
         "id":6,
         "name":"Alert Test 416"
      },
      "source":{  
         "type":"Service",
         "id":37379,
         "name":"489-127-2367"
      },
      "value":1310384.000000    },    {  
      "id":1,
      "time":"2018-04-15 22:04:21",
      "alert":{  
         "id":6,
         "name":"Alert Test 416"
      },
      "source":{  
         "type":"Service",
         "id":37826,
         "name":"489-332-4137"
      },
      "value":1352071.000000    },    {  
      "id":2,
      "time":"2018-04-16 22:04:36",
      "alert":{  
         "id":6,
         "name":"Alert Test 416"
      },
      "source":{  
         "type":"Service",
         "id":37364,
         "name":"489-776-9604"
      },
      "value":6021.000000    }
```

There are two entries with id = 1 and one entry with id = 2. I would like to see an output like below,

```html
<tbody> 
<tr id="1" role="row"> 
<td>2018-04-15 22:04:21</td><td>Alert Test 416</td><td>Service</td><td>489-127-2367</td></tr> 
<tr id="1" role="row"> 
<td>2018-04-15 22:04:21</td><td>Alert Test 416</td><td>Service</td><td>489-332-4137</td></tr> 
<tr id="2" role="row"> 
<td>2018-04-16 22:04:36</td><td>Alert Test 416</td><td>Service</td><td>489-776-9604</td></tr> 
</tbody>
```

But I get an output like below instead,

```html
<tbody> 
<tr id="1" role="row"> 
<td>2018-04-15 22:04:21</td><td>Alert Test 416</td><td>Service</td><td>489-127-2367</td></tr> 
<tr id="2" role="row"> 
<td>2018-04-16 22:04:36</td><td>Alert Test 416</td><td>Service</td><td>489-776-9604</td></tr> 
</tbody>
```

The code only takes the very first entry for each top level id and then moves to the next id.

Here is the code,

```
<tbody>
              {history.map((item) => {
  return <tr key={item.id} id={item.id} role='row'>
  <td>{item.time}</td>
  <td>{item.alert.name}</td>
  <td>{item.source.type}</td>
  <td>{item.source.name}</td>
</tr>
  })}
</tbody>
```

The history is the object containing the JSON input shown above. How should the above be modified so that I get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are specifying the id as the key which is not unique, only one of the elements with duplicate key is rendered, if you don't have any option for using a unique key form the data you might prefer to go for the index like

```
<tbody>
  {history.map((item, index) => {
     return <tr key={index} id={item.id} role='row'>
        <td>{item.time}</td>
        <td>{item.alert.name}</td>
        <td>{item.source.type}</td>
        <td>{item.source.name}</td>
     </tr>
  })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shubham. That was the exact solution I needed and it worked like a charm. I did not quite know the use of index, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: index is an option to provide as a key, but if possible you must avoid using it as it doesn't quite have the best of performance since the index to data mapping can change if the order of data is changed or a data is deleted from the middle

Answer (score 2):

```
_.map(history, (item, index) => {
   return (<tr key={index} id={item.id} role='row'>
            <td>{item.time}</td>
         </tr>)
});
```

You should always use Key for displaying unique attributes instead of ids. I have used Lodash map here, which is a good library to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't have two elements with the same key or id, so only one of them is being shown.

Instead of having multiple 's with the same id, just use 1, and then use additional 's if you want to display more data about the same id.

Comment: Thanks Joey, yes I had understood why it was happening but was wondering if there was a way to fix it in the jsx code, instead of having to edit the object itself, as that would be more complex in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your key does not duplicate. One of the ways of it's avoiding duplicate, concat somethings with the array index. there is no change for duplicates. like..

```
{history.map((item, index) => {
 return <tr key={index + item.id} id={item.id} role='row'>
     <td>{item.time}</td>
      ....
   </tr>
})}
```